# Read Object from HttpServletRequest in Spring controller

Tags: java, json, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am sending class object to my spring controller. But the HttpServletRequest accept only String not object.Here is my code

download.jsp

```
<a class="download_excel view_download" >Download Full Excel</a>
<input type="hidden" class="result-object" value="${ReportDetails}" />

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() 
        {
            $('.view_download').click(function()
            {
                var object = $('.result-object').val();
                window.location.href =   "excelDownload.html?data="+object;     
            });
        });

    Controller file: HomeController.java

    @RequestMapping(value="/excelDownload", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    private ModelAndView excelDownload(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String result = request.getParameter("data");
        return null;
    }

</script>
```

But I need the following QueryResult object from HttpServletResquest not string.

```
    QueryResult result = request.getParameter("data");
```

Help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: http is all about strings there is nothing else to transfer from the client to the server. You need to use a converter to convert the string into the object you need.

Comment: @balaraman you might need to convert your object to `json` at client side and then retrieve at server side.

Comment: yes.But how do we convert those string into my class object.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can help you to fix this.
change this

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/excelDownload", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   private ModelAndView excelDownload(HttpServletRequest request)
   {
```

with

```
      @RequestMapping(value="/excelDownload", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       private ModelAndView excelDownload(HttpServletRequest         
        request,@RequestParam YourObject     
        object)
   {  .....}
```

Comment: yes.If I am using the YourObject. it prints null..we only get it from request